# \* - \? using xcopy (cmd)

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to export/import the bookmarks that I have in Firefox with a batch file.

The path is:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\???????.default\
```

and these (?) are different in all the computers.

I am using this:

```
xcopy "C:\users\%username%\desktop\test\????????.default\*" "C:\users\%username%\desktop\test2\aa2"
```

And it says:

```
File not found - *
```

I would like to copy all the folders and files that are inside of `\???.default\` and not the folder because as I mention before this are different.

Comment: What happens when you enter the following at the command prompt? **`For /D %A In ("%LocalAppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default") Do @Echo("%A"`**

Comment: it is returning the name of the folder: Profiles\0k6xqa82.default")

Comment: So, you should be able to replace **`Echo(`**, with your copy command, shouldn't you?

Comment: The wildcards `?` and `*` can be used on Windows command line only in string after last backslash, i.e. file/folder __name__, but __not__ in file/folder __path__. The solution is using __FOR__ to get the variable name of folder `*.default` and use that folder name in the command(s). That is what [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) suggested absolutely right and perfect working.

Comment: Yes, its working now. :) but why is not working when I typed this in my .bat? Thanks

Comment: In a batch file you need to replace **`%A`** with **`%%A`**.

Comment: Thanks guys everything is working now.